# CYPHER POST request to Neo4J API

Tags: r, api, neo4j, cypher, httr

The following `curl` request works perfectly fine, it returns the desired JSON.

```bash
curl \
  -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{"statements": [{"statement": "MATCH (n:Chemical) WHERE n.xrefCasRN = \"1071-83-6\" RETURN n;"}]}' \
  http://neo4j.comptox.ai:7474/db/data/transaction > result.json
```

I'd like to translate this request into R using the `httr` package, however I'm not able to retrieve the JSON as in the `curl` request.

```r
require(httr)

baseurl = 'http://neo4j.comptox.ai:7474/db/data/transaction'
body = '{"statements": [{"statement": "MATCH (n:Chemical) WHERE n.xrefCasRN = \"1071-83-6\" RETURN n;"}]}'
res = httr::POST(
  baseurl,
  httr::content_type_json(),
  httr::verbose(),
  body = body
)
httr::content(res)
```

The HTTP status code is 201 and I wondered whether I have to download the 'Created' data somehow, to no avail though. Also, not being able to download the data isn't an issue for `curl`.

```r
qurl = httr::headers(res)$location
download.file(qurl, 'test.json')
```

What's the difference between the `curl` and the R `httr` request, and why does the latter not work?